# Searchable Dropdown in Website - Django - Saving to data base

Tags: python, django, list, drop-down-menu, searchable

I am building a website and part of it involves a drop-down which is easily called in the HTML by {{ form.inspection_type }}. This is a pretty big drop-down and a pain to scroll all the way to what you need to select so I have been trying for the past few days to implement a searchable drop-down to replace it. I have tried every single library I would find on searchable drop-downs and non have worked with the specifics of my project. I have reverted to doing it through HTML and have again gone through about 40 different examples and iterations and have gotten close. The **NEW** code is a searchable drop-down that is populated with my Django database drop-down. However when I click submit it shows that no data was added to the list view that I have. Below is the old code that worked and didn't have a searchable drop-down and also I have added the new code that has the searchable drop-down but won't submit the data through. Let me know if I missed anything and you have any questions. Thanks!

OLD - works but no searchable drop-down

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form.inspection_type }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

NEW - doesn't submit but has searchable drop-do

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input list="Dealer" name="Dealer">
    <datalist class="SmallFormField" name="Dealer" id="Dealer" onChange="submitForm(this.form, true)" onkeypress="gblKeyPress()" onkeydown="gblKeyDown()" onfocus="gblOnFocus('Dealer')" onblur="gblOnBlur()" onClick="gblOnClick('QuoteMgrSearchCriteria', this.form)">
    <option value="">Select a Dealer ...</option>
    <option value="2919">{{ form.inspection_type }}</option>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT:**

Working with no search:
[image]

Not submitting with search:
[image]

forms.py

```
class SheetForm_Building(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Sheet_Building
    fields = '__all__'
    exclude = ['user']

    widgets = {
        'inspection_type': forms.Select(choices=INSPECTION_TYPE_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'department': forms.Select(choices=DEPARTMENT_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'concern': forms.Select(choices=CONCERN_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'hazard_level': forms.Select(choices=HAZARD_LEVEL_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'building_address': forms.Select(choices=BUILDING_ADDRESS_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'floor': forms.Select(choices=FLOOR_LEVEL_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'location': forms.Select(choices=LOCATION_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'codes': forms.Select(choices=CODES_BI, attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    }
```

models.py:

```
class Sheet_Building(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=True, related_name="Building", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Date')
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Time')
    inspection_type = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=INSPECTION_TYPE_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspection Type')
    flname = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Inspector')
    report_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Report Date')
    department = models.CharField(max_length=29, choices=DEPARTMENT_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Department')
    responsible_name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Responsible Person')
    building_address = models.CharField(max_length=52, choices=BUILDING_ADDRESS, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Building and Address')
    floor = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=FLOOR_LEVEL_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Floor / Level')
    room = models.CharField(max_length=35, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Area / Room')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=LOCATION_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Location')
    priority = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Priority')
    hazard_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=HAZARD_LEVEL_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Hazard Level')
    concern = models.CharField(max_length=31, choices=CONCERN_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Concern')
    codes = models.CharField(max_length=51, choices=CODES_BI, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Element and Code')
   correction = models.TextField(max_length=160, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Corrective Action')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='Image', upload_to='gallery')
    notes = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Inspector's note")

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.flname or 'None'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('list_building')
```

**EDIT2:**

These are the changes I've done to get your suggested view to get it a little closer

```
INSPECTION_TYPE_BI = (
    ('Building Code', 'Building Code'),
    ('DEP / EPA', 'DEP / EPA'),
    ('DEP / OSHA', 'DEP / OSHA'),
    ('DEP / EPA / OSHA', 'DEP / EPA / OSHA'),
    ('Electrical Code', 'Electrical Code'),
    ('Elevator Code', 'Elevator Code'),
    ('Fire Code', 'Fire Code'),
    ('Laboratory', 'Laboratory'),
    ('Life Safety', 'Life Safety'),
    ('Multi-Media', 'Multi-Media'),
    ('OSHA', 'OSHA'),
    ('Playground', 'Playground'),
    ('Satellite Area', 'Satellite Area'),
    ('Town of Amherst', 'Town of Amherst'),
    ('Health', 'Health'),
    ('Kitchen', 'Kitchen'),
)

def adddata_building(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # To make sure that the option we selected is being sent in the form data
        print(request.POST)
    form = SheetForm_Building()
    optionList = INSPECTION_TYPE_BI[1:]
    return render(request, "testapp/layout.html", {
        "form": form,
        "optionList": optionList
    })
```

This is a form I typically use that works to submit but it doesn't have a searchable dropdown functionality.

```
def adddata_building(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = SheetForm_Building(response.POST, response.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = response.user
            instance.save()
            response.user.Building.add(instance)
            return redirect('list_building')
    else:
        form = SheetForm_Building()
    return render(response, 'sheets/add_data/add_data_building.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is where I currently am in integrating the two to have a form with a searchable dropdown that can also submit. This submits the form and all other fields in the form however it does not submit the searchable dropdown field. It shows all other fields that has been submitted and their values but shows no indication that the searchable dropdown field has any value to it submitted...

```
def adddata_building(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = SheetForm_Building(response.POST, response.FILES)
        optionList = INSPECTION_TYPE_BI[1:]
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = response.user
            instance.save()
            response.user.Building.add(instance)
            return redirect('list_building')
    else:
        form = SheetForm_Building()
        optionList = INSPECTION_TYPE_BI[1:]
    return render(response, 'sheets/add_data/add_data_building.html', {'form': form, 'optionList': optionList})
```

Comment: Could you show what form.inspection_type prints out on the page?

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui it prints out one of the following which are also the options in the drop-down
    ('Building Code'),
    ('DEP / EPA'),
    ('DEP / OSHA', ),
    ('DEP / EPA / OSHA'),
    ('Electrical Code'),
    ('Elevator Code', 'Elevator Code'),
    ('Fire Code', 'Fire Code'),
    ('Laboratory', 'Laboratory'),
    ('Life Safety', 'Life Safety'),
    ('Multi-Media', 'Multi-Media'),
    ('OSHA', 'OSHA'),
    ('Playground', 'Playground'),
    ('Satellite Area', 'Satellite Area'),
    ('Town of Amherst', 'Town of Amherst'),
    ('Health', 'Health'),
    ('Kitchen', 'Kitchen'),

Comment: There are repeats just ignore them they are for the syntax

Comment: I've edited my original answer. Have a look, and let me know if there are any other issues

Comment: When you say it is not saving, are you encountering an error when you try to save the instance? Or does everything seem as if it works, but when you try to print this value later you're getting 'None'?

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui Using the modified view that you sent which is the first view shown in EDIT2 when submit is click the website stays on the same page and does not change to another, there is no indication that the form submitted, and even where I can view that data there is no new post. So it doesn't give an error but no data is submitted. Continued on next comment...

Comment: @OmarSiddiqui The third view show in EDIT2 of the post above which is a form that will submit all other fields except the searchable dropdown also doesn't come up with an error when submit is clicked, it does however redirect to the page where the data is displayed and it even shows that data was submitted but just returns the searchable dropdown as "None"  and all other fields as their proper values given in the form.

Comment: 2nd edit is done. If this still doesn't work out, we should probably move this discussion to a chat. These comments are getting too long lol

Comment: @OmarSidddiqui FINALLY!! Thanks so much for your help this works perfectly and is way better than the dysfunctional libraries I have seen out there. Works like a charm, Thank you so much

Comment: That's great to hear! If you liked the answer, then upvoting it would help me :)

Comment: No problem, have a great one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I'm not sure why, in the form inspection type you have 2 values only for some of the options.

In Django, when creating the options/choices list, data is entered as a list of tuples [(a,b), (c,d) ...] with the first option in the tuple being the value that is actually stored and the second option being the label/human-readable part in the dropdown. You can see what I'm talking about [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#field-choices). That's the first potential issue I'm noticing; the fact that you only have 2 values for some of them.

The second thing I'm noticing is that, in the new version, your option value is  hardcoded to be 2919. I think that that may be the main cause of the issue. If you were to print `request.POST` you'd see a key-value pair of `'Dealer': ['2919']` in the QueryDict that is printed. You're submitting a value which is probably not matching anything in your list.

So, I personally would recommend doing something similar to what I've done before:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input list="Dealer" name="Dealer">
    <datalist class="SmallFormField" name="Dealer" id="Dealer" onChange="submitForm(this.form, true)" onkeypress="gblKeyPress()" onkeydown="gblKeyDown()" onfocus="gblOnFocus('Dealer')" onblur="gblOnBlur()" onClick="gblOnClick('QuoteMgrSearchCriteria', this.form)">
    <option value="">Select a Dealer ...</option>
    {% for option in optionList %}
    <option value="{{option.0}}">{{ option.1 }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Just pass in whatever optionsList you've defined directly to the template and use the templating language's for loop to populate the options in the  tag.

Hope this works for you

**EDIT:**

Alright, I've got a clearer idea of how you're generating your forms. Thanks for that extra info. Here's what I would do. I'm pretty sure someone out there would have a better method, but for now this will work for you.

Django does not have an inbuilt widget for datalists, and customizing existing widget files/ creating new widgets is a bit too complicated for me. So what I'm going to do is show you a way to fit the code I've written earlier with what you've got currently.

In views.py:

```
from .models import Sheet_Building
from .forms import SheetForm_Building

def YourViewName(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # To make sure that the option we selected is being sent in the form data
        print(request.POST)
    form = SheetForm_Building()
    optionList = Sheet_Building.INSPECTION_TYPE_BI[1:]
    return render(request, "testapp/layout.html", {
        "form": form,
        "optionList": optionList
    })
```

In the html file, I've spread the form fields (as was shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)), so that we render the dataList where it would usually appear in the form, instead of right at the beginning or at the end.

We're going to loop through all fields in the form until we come across `form.inspection_type`. At this point, we won't use the default Django input field, but rather define our own in the html. So `{{ field.label_tag }}` will be used as is, but `{{ field }}` will be replaced by the code for the datalist.

Here is what the file will look like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% for field in form %}
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
  {{ field.errors }}
  {% if field == form.inspection_type %}
  {{ field.label_tag}}
  <input list="id_inspection_type" name="inspection_type">
  <datalist name="inspection_type" id="id_inspection_type">
  <option value="">Select a Dealer ...</option>
  {% for option in optionList %}
  <option value="{{option.0}}">{{ option.1 }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
  </datalist>
  {% else %}
  {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
  {% endif %}
  {% if field.help_text %}
  <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

And here is a screenshot of the request.POST:

[image: Screenshot of submitted form data]

As you can see, the option selected in the datalist (Electrical Code) was submitted through the form without any issues.

**EDIT 2:**

I used the ID and name *(Dealer)* that you've used in your code. The problem with using this is that in your model *Sheet_Building*, you have a field called *inspection_type*. Your form *SheetForm_Building* is created from this model. So it also has a field *inspection_type*.

When you try to save this form, it will make sure that the values submitted in the POST request are the same as what were defined.

Now what's happening in your case is that when you're submitting data with the name *Dealer*, the formData gets a key with the same name, which is not what your instance/model was expecting. So although the data has been submitted through the form, it was not mapped to anything because your model has no field *Dealer*. This is why even though everything else gets saved, this particular field has a value of None.

To fix this issue, keep the **name** attribute the same as what you've defined in your form. ie. **inspection_type**

```
<input list="id_inspection_type" name="inspection_type">
<datalist id="id_inspection_type">
```

Comment: 1st sorry about that last comment I didn't know one was supposed to be readable and the other not I will fix that. Also the comment space ran out of characters so I had to erase some but I don't think that is the problem. Im not sure how to implement the code you have show in your post. {{ form.inspection_type }} is not included and Im not sure where it needs to go however I now see the point of the forloop. Thank You!

Comment: You're welcome. I was still a bit confused by how exactly {{form.inspection_type}} was working so I suggested what I felt was a simpler option. Because, if it's only a single value, then how were you rendering an entire dropdown? Perhaps a screenshot or something of what it looks like in the browser would make things clearer

Comment: I edited my post to show my forms.py my models.py and screenshots, I also added the table that my model and form is referring to but the problem is mostly HTML seeing that one version of the HTML works but has no search and one version of the HTML doesn't work but has a search. Hope this helps

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote and the form now does submit but it is a character field now with no dropdown. It does however restrict the user from submitting anything that is not is the list of an item which is a step in the right direction its just now Im not so sure how to include the drop-down and integrate it with the search. This is definitely a step in the right direction and will help a lot of people, Im going to continue to work on it but I'm still a little stuck

Comment: @Russell There is an <input> tag before the <datalist> tag. Make sure that the list attribute in the <input> tag has the same value as the id attribute in the <datalist> tag, the dropdown won't show up and it'll work only as a regular input

Comment: Sorry I just missed that while I was doing my final edit. My input and datalist tags now look like this <input list="Dealer" name="Dealer"> <datalist name="Dealer" id="Dealer">.   This almost works. I had to do one more edit however in the views.py file. The line optionList = Sheet_Building.INSPECTION_TYPE_BI[1:] gave an error message but it was easily solved by changing it to optionList = INSPECTION_TYPE_BI[1:] and adding the selection options in the views.py file. This is super super close but the form doesn't submit. Continued on next comment....

Comment: I edited my original post titled "EDIT2:" which shows the edits I've done to the view that you sent me to get it closer to working. I've also added a view that I usually use that submits the form just fine but doesn't have a searchable dropdown in this case. And on top of that Ive added my attempt so far at combining the two to have the searchable dropdown and have it submit. This is going to help a lot of people including myself, thanks so much for your help so far. We are really close

Comment: @Russell I don't see any Edit 2

Comment: Just added it, I didn't think you would respond that quick. :)